Automatic renaming of layer based on symbology Value set for it
In QGIS I can display the same data source but with different representations based on the symbology I set for it. Thus I can have multiple layers of the same data source but each one is displayed with a different symbology based on different attributes or values. Manual renaming to distinguish them always takes a lot of time. How can I have these layers automatically renamed (in the layers panel) with the Value (or a concatenation with it) tha was set in the symbology settings?

You can use PyQGIS. Rename like this. First you need to find a way of reading the symbol value
